# Modify first and second occurrence and reset of a string

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I have the following string

```
$data = '
<tr>
    <td>Section Head 1</td>
    <td>DATA DATA DATA DATA 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Section Head 2</td>
    <td>DATA DATA DATA DATA 2</td>
</tr>';
```

I want to modify it to become like this:

```
<tr>
    <td width="25%;">Section Head 1</td>
    <td width="75%;">DATA DATA DATA DATA 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="25%;">Section Head 2</td>
    <td width="75%;">DATA DATA DATA DATA 2</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to use `preg_replace('td', '$1 width="25%"', $data);`

But I'm stuck, I cant figure out how to do this in a single preg_replace

Comment: Do you generate this string with PHP?

Comment: Yeah, this is a code that is inside my DB, and I want to replace the code on echo/print

Comment: How do you generate this in the first place? Would be easier to alter it when generated, or perhaps with jQuery or a DOM parser. Or using CSS.

Comment: Why? How come using a stylesheet is not an option?

Comment: @mario - the data is not changeable. But i could change the table style, if you have a suggestion

Comment: @Qirel - the data is inserted using WYSIWYG textarea, what i need to do is, style it after submitting to db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS property, and find even and odd occurrances in that pattern.

In this example, we have a table with the ID of `myTable`, where all the even children of `<td>` gets 25% width, odd children gets 75% width.

```css
table#myTable tr td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 25%;
}
table#myTable tr td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
      <td>Section Head 1</td>
      <td>DATA DATA DATA DATA 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Section Head 2</td>
      <td>DATA DATA DATA DATA 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So you would do

```
<table id="myTable">
    <?php echo $data; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that, would of been a much easier solution